# Hide textbox when clicking off box (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I've got three icons. When I click one, I'm appending an overlay (like a light box), then popping up a textbox explaining the icon, then hiding the textbox when the overlay is clicked.

I've gotten everything down except when I click on the box again, the textbox doesn't appear again. Do I need to do some kind of refresh or something?

HTML:

```
 <div class="serviceOption">
    <a class="iconAnchor"> <i id="bigIcon" class="fa fa-laptop fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <label for="serviceCheckbox"> Technology Audits</label>
 </div>
 <div id="techPopup" for="anchor1" class="popupBox"> 
    <h2>HEADLINE 1</h2>
    <p> Popup text 1<p>
 </div>

<div class="serviceOption">
   <a class="iconAnchor"><i id="bigIcon" class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   <label for="serviceCheckbox1"> Cloud Solutions</label>
</div>
  <div id="cloudPopup" class="popupBox"> 
     <h2>HEADLINE 2</h2>
     <p> Popup text 2<p>
  </div>

<div class="serviceOption">
   <a class="iconAnchor"><i id="bigIcon" class="fa fa-envelope fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   <label for="serviceCheckbox2"> Email Solutions</label>
</div>
<div id="cloudPopup" class="popupBox"> 
   <h2>HEADLINE 3</h2>
   <p>Popup text 3</p> 
</div>
```

and my JQuery:

```
/* ----------- SERVICES TOGGLE ON SERVICES PAGE--------------- */
// 1. Create overlay and append it to body
var overlay = $('<div id=overlay></div>');
$('body').append(overlay);


$('.iconAnchor').click(function(){
  var serviceParagraph = $(this).closest('.serviceOption').next('.popupBox');
  overlay.show();
  overlay.append(serviceParagraph);
  serviceParagraph.slideDown();
}); // end ICON click

$(overlay).click(function(event){
  $('.popupBox').slideUp(200);    
  overlay.hide();
}); // end OVERLAY click
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use jQuery, slideToggle() is perfect for this use case...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.popupBox').hide();
  $('.iconAnchor').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.serviceOption').next('.popupBox').slideToggle();
  });
  $('.popupBox').click(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle();
  })
});
```

**EDIT**

So I think there are probably better ways to what you want but for the sake of preserving your overlay div, this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var overlay = $('<div id=overlay></div>'); 
  $('body').append(overlay);
  $('.popupBox').hide();
  $('.iconAnchor').click(function(){
    overlay.empty().html($(this).closest('.serviceOption').next('.popupBox').html());
    overlay.slideDown();
  });
  overlay.click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp();
  })
});
```

Also, the reason why your original code isn't working as you expect is because when you append the popupBox element to your overlay div it is actually being moved inside of the div and no longer exists where you expect it to be the next time that click handler for the iconAnchor is called. This means that your `serviceParagraph.slideDown()` is being called on an empty element.

Comment: That works, but it leaves out the overlay. When I put it back in my script, it still has the same problem as before:

JQ:

       var overlay = $('<div id=overlay></div>');
    $('body').append(overlay);

    $('.popupBox').hide();
    $('.iconAnchor').click(function(){
       var textBox = $(this).closest('.serviceOption').next('.popupBox');
       (overlay).append(textBox);
       overlay.show();
       textBox.slideToggle(200);
      
       });
      $('.popupBox').click(function(){
         $(this).slideToggle();
         overlay.hide();
       });

Comment: Sorry about the mess there too, it wouldn't let me format it

Comment: I removed the overlay portion b/c it wasn't necessary to accomplish what you were describing.  Do you need an extra div to wrap these pop-up divs?

Comment: I do! I wanted to click the icon, make it look the whole background fades grey, and pop up the textbox at the same time. I used jQuery to create an overlay, and tried to append it. What am I doing wrong the reason it will only pop up the boxes once, but not again until I refresh the page?

Comment: I updated the answer with another solution that will keep your overlay and still function the way you want it to... I also addressed why your original method wasn't working.